# admin user creation is giving error in mongodb 3.0

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-3.0

I am trying to create admin user in mongoDB and it's giving me following error. MongoDB 3.0 version is being used.

Error :
`2015-12-10T15:23:47.065+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't add user: Could not lock auth data update lock.
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DB.createUser (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1101:11)
    at (shell):1:4 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1101`

I have followed the link below to create the admin user.
link : https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/enable-authentication/

```
    use admin
    db.createUser(
                  {
                     user: "myUserAdmin",
                     pwd: "abc123",
                     roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db:"admin" } ]
                  }
                 )
```

Comment: Can you verify you didn't start mongo with authentication enabled first? It has to be disabled to create the first user, so if your config enabled authentication when you started it, you need to start over.

Comment: No, Authentication is not enabled.

Comment: This is interesting.  Have you managed to fix this issue?  If you haven't post it in MongoDB Google group